# vertical centre modal with aspect 16:9

Tags: html, css

I have a modal popup that I have an aspect ratio of 16:9.

I want to vertical centre the blue popup on the screen and still always maintain the aspect ratio.

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div>Aspect is kept when resizing</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 0.85;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 9 / 16);
}
.child > div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is a demo of what I have. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/nqL10ezp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one div solution. I do not like to use transform to get vertical center as you can get blurry text at odd height values.

https://jsfiddle.net/nqL10ezp/2/

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 9 / 16);
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.parent {
    position: absolute;           /* instead of relative */
    top:50%;                      /* push to 50% top */
    transform: translateY(-50%);  /* bring back at -50% own height */
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;           /* instead of relative */
  top:50%;                      /* push to 50% top */
  transform: translateY(-50%);  /* bring back at -50% own height */
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% * 9 / 16);
}
.child > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div>Aspect is kept when resizing</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, it seems aligned to the bottom of the screen and I have to scroll down

Comment: @KeithPower well, that's cause your original script does not handles vertical resize. have you seen that demo in full screen?

Comment: @KeithPower CSS3! add `-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);`